# set MFA options for user using keystoneclient module

Tags: openstack, multi-factor-authentication, openstack-keystone

I am trying to [enable default MFA for Openstack](https://docs.openstack.org/keystone/latest/admin/multi-factor-authentication.html#multi-factor-authentication) user using Python keystoneclient API
[keystoneclient.users.update](https://docs.openstack.org/python-keystoneclient/ussuri/api/keystoneclient.v3.html#keystoneclient.v3.users.UserManager.update)

I have sample API curl command from Openstack documentation, where you update the ["options" attribute of user account with JSON object](https://docs.openstack.org/keystone/latest/admin/resource-options.html#multi-factor-auth-rules)

```
{
"user": {
    "options": {
        "multi_factor_auth_enabled": true,
        "multi_factor_auth_rules": [
            ["password", "totp"]
        ]
    }
}
```

}

when I am trying to update the same in Python code I am getting below error

> > keystoneauth1.exceptions.http.BadRequest: Invalid input for field 'options': u'{ "multi_factor_auth_enabled": true,
> > "multi_factor_auth_rules": [["password", "totp"]]}' is not of type
> > 'object'
>
> Failed validating 'type' in schema['properties']['options']:

my code is like this

```
MFA_dict = '{ "multi_factor_auth_enabled": true, "multi_factor_auth_rules": [["password", "totp"]]}'
    user = keystone.users.update(user_id, options=MFA_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I figured it out.
MFA_dict was string, so I had to just remove single quotes and make the object dictionary.

and make lower case true into uppercase **True** to make it boolean

```
MFA_dict = { "multi_factor_auth_enabled": True, "multi_factor_auth_rules": [["password", "totp"]]}
```